# How do I set up Gitorious server on ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, git

I wanted to know how I can set up gitorious server on ubuntu and have it work locally. I'm running 12.04 and would like to get the latest version

Comment: Please see - http://askubuntu.com/questions/12647/setting-up-a-git-server & http://askubuntu.com/questions/25131/how-to-setup-a-git-server

Comment: i got: undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module see here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YgV9Sym7
and here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3LYTygS0 BR,
daniel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** As of Gitorious 3.2 (beginning of 2015) gitorious supports ubuntu directly. See https://gitorious.org/gitorious/ce-installer/ for installation instructions.

Original instructions:

To install gitorious the latest one from git, follow these steps

First, lets go root by using

```
sudo su
[sudo] password for <username>:
```

## Installing packages

When installing all these packages, you will be asked for a MySQL root password, which you should remember, because you will need it later on.

```
  aptitude install \
    build-essential zlib1g-dev tcl-dev libexpat-dev libxslt1-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev postfix apache2 mysql-server mysql-client \
    apg geoip-bin libgeoip1 libgeoip-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev \
    imagemagick libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libyaml-dev \
    libmysqlclient15-dev apache2-dev libonig-dev ruby-dev rubygems \
    libopenssl-ruby libdbd-mysql-ruby libmysql-ruby \
    libmagick++-dev zip unzip memcached git-core git-svn git-doc \
    git-cvs irb
```

## Installing the Ruby Gems

`Gem.source_index` is being deprecated. Using system 1.8.25 avoids the source_index error.

```
REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM=1 gem update --system 1.8.25
```

Now we can install all the necessary gems:

```
  gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc -v 0.8.7 rake && \
    gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc -v 1.1.0 daemons && \
    gem install -b --no-ri --no-rdoc \
        rmagick stompserver passenger bundler
```

## Installing the Sphinx Search Server

```
wget http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-0.9.9.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf sphinx-0.9.9.tar.gz && \
    cd sphinx-0.9.9 && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
    make all install
```

## Getting Gitorious

```
  git clone git://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline.git /var/www/gitorious && \
    cd /var/www/gitorious && \
    git submodule init && \
    git submodule update
```

Easy as pie. Now we just need to put the Gitorious binary on our path:

```
 ln -s /var/www/gitorious/script/gitorious /usr/bin
```

## Configuring services

Gitorious needs a bunch of background services, so we need to copy the supplied startup scripts:

```
cd /var/www/gitorious/doc/templates/ubuntu/ && \
    cp git-daemon git-poller git-ultrasphinx stomp /etc/init.d/ && \
    cd /etc/init.d/ && \
    chmod 755 git-daemon git-poller git-ultrasphinx stomp
```

and enable them:

```
 update-rc.d git-daemon defaults && \
    update-rc.d git-poller defaults && \
    update-rc.d git-ultrasphinx defaults && \
    update-rc.d stomp defaults
```

We need to create an additional symlink, because all the startup scripts have RUBY_HOME set to /opt/ruby-enterprise (alternatively we could just patch the files, but this way it is easier and you can update the scripts if needed):

```
 ln -s /usr/ /opt/ruby-enterprise
```

### Fixing git-ultrasphinx

As of March 2013 the git-ultrasphinx script is broken and will fail to start. Please edit `/etc/init.d/git-ultrasphinx` and check that the `start`, `stop` and `restart` commands are as follows (replace `ultrasphinx:daemon` with `ts` if necessary):

```
 START_CMD="cd $GITORIOUS_HOME && rake ts:start RAILS_ENV=production"
 STOP_CMD="cd $GITORIOUS_HOME && rake ts:stop RAILS_ENV=production"
 RESTART_CMD="cd $GITORIOUS_HOME && rake ts:restart RAILS_ENV=production"
```

## Configuring Apache

### Passenger

First of all, we need to compile the Apache2 passenger module:

$(gem contents passenger | grep passenger-install-apache2-module)

The passenger configuration script will tell you exactly what you’ll need to add to your apache configuration. The part you need to copy looks like this:

Please edit your Apache configuration file, and add these lines:

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

After you restart Apache, you are ready to deploy any number of Ruby on Rails
applications on Apache, without any further Ruby on Rails-specific
configuration!
These three lines need to be inserted into

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load
```

## Enabling necessary modules

```
   a2enmod passenger && \
        a2enmod rewrite && \
        a2enmod ssl
```

Creating the Apache2 sites

Type in :

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/gitorious
```

And copy paste the following text

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your.server.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gitorious/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Type in

```
 nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/gitorious-ssl
```

And copy paste the following text

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/gitorious/public
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now we need to disable the default site, and enable our freshly created Gitorious sites:

```
  a2dissite default && \
    a2dissite default-ssl && \
    a2ensite gitorious && \
    a2ensite gitorious-ssl
```

## Creating a MySQL user for gitorious

```
  mysql -u root -p
```

Enter the password you made while installing MySQL after the following prompt

```
Enter password:
```

Type this in line by line excluding the `mysql>` and changing `<insert password>` with your MySQL password you made while installing MySQL

```
 mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'gitorious'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<insert password>' WITH GRANT OPTION;

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## Configuring Gitorious

First of all, we need to make sure we have all gems in the correct version for Gitorious, so we run the following:

```
cd /var/www/gitorious/ && \
    bundle install && \
    bundle pack
```

Now we can create the user under which Gitorious will run and serve the Git repositories:

```
  adduser --system --home /var/www/gitorious/ --no-create-home --group --shell /bin/bash git && \
    chown -R git:git /var/www/gitorious
```

Then we need to create some stuff that Gitorious needs to run:

```
  su - git && \
    mkdir .ssh && \
    touch .ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chmod 700 .ssh && \
    chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys && \
    mkdir tmp/pids && \
    mkdir repositories && \
    mkdir tarballs
```

## Creating the Gitorious configuration

Lets copy the sample configuration files to the correct path:

```
 cp config/database.sample.yml config/database.yml && \
    cp config/gitorious.sample.yml config/gitorious.yml && \
    cp config/broker.yml.example config/broker.yml
```

Now edit the config/database.yml and make sure you set the correct username and password in the production section. After that, we need to set a couple of things in config/gitorious.yml:

Make sure you are configuring the right section (not test:, but production:)

```
repository_base_path should be /var/www/gitorious/repositories
cookie_secret needs to be set to a random value >= 30 characters
gitorious_client_port should be 80
gitorious_host needs to be the exact hostname that clients will use (cookies get messed up otherwise)
archive_cache_dir should be /var/www/gitorious/tarballs
archive_work_dir should be something like /tmp/tarballs-work
hide_http_clone_urls should be true (they require extra unknown setup to work)
is_gitorious_dot_org should be false
Creating the Gitorious database
```

Because of an incompatibility of RubyGems with Rails < 2.3.11 you need to add the following line at the top of config/boot.rb:

```
require 'thread'
```

Now we let rake do all the work for us:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production && \
    bundle exec rake db:create && \
    bundle exec rake db:migrate && \
    bundle exec rake rake ts:conf && \
    bundle exec rake rake ts:rebuild
```

## Create the Sphinx Cronjob

```
crontab -e 10 * * * * /var/www/gitorious/bin/rake ts:rebuild >/dev/null RAILS_ENV=production
```

## Create an admin user

```
env RAILS_ENV=production ruby1.8 script/create_admin
```

Reboot

You’re finally done. Reboot your Ubuntu machine, and your Gitorious installation should be up and running.

## Checking possible problems

Browse http://your.server.com/admin/diagnostics in order to check for possible problems.

---

**Source**: http://coding-journal.com/installing-gitorious-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: These (above) instructions didn't work for me. [http://edin.no-ip.com/comment/286](http://edin.no-ip.com/comment/286) did, except for getting https.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try my auto-installer :

http://blog.celogeek.com/201211/272/gitorious-installer-for-ubuntu/

https://gitorious.celogeek.com/gitorious-installer

Tell me if it work for you.